# Regex match center of a string

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the center of this string , everything except "import " and the semicolon.
The first part of this regex works , but the semicolon is still present.

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
```

Regex

```
(?![\bimport \b]).*(?![;])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one using positive lookbehind and lookahead.

```
(?<=import ).*?(?=;)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which regex tool you're using but you can use this regex:

```
import +([^;]+)
```

and grab matched group #1.

Above example would give you: `javax.faces.application.FacesMessage`